# graphstream: FileSinkImages to png doesn't work well with parallels edges

Tags: java, graph, graphstream

I'm trying to plot an image using FileSinkImages:

```
FileSinkImages pic = new FileSinkImages(OutputType.png, Resolutions.HD720);
pic.setLayoutPolicy(LayoutPolicy.COMPUTED_FULLY_AT_NEW_IMAGE);
pic.setQuality(Quality.HIGH);
pic.writeAll(graph, filename);

graph.display();
```

The displayed image is correct: parallels edges are curved lines, in the plotted image are overlapping lines.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
pic.setRenderer(RendererType.SCALA);
```

I think that

```
System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui.renderer", "org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");
```

has no effect on image renderer.